# Cypress removes user-agent header after every page changing

Tags: javascript, header, cypress, request-headers

I am writing some tests for mobile and tablet devices. I should use user-agent header while writing this tests. When i adding user-agent to cy.visit path with this method it works fine;

```js
cy.visit("/mypath", {
  headers: { "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_2_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1",
  },
});
```

But after changing page with click or similar methods (Click methods requests another page), my user-agent have lost. I tried to add userAgent to cypress.json file but that is not working for my test pages. I can only used it on cy.visit method. How can i add this header to all my test suites pages ? Thanks for your helping.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am facing the same issue

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: update using `cypress@10.7.0`, added `userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_2_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1",` inside  `e2e: { ... }` in the `config.js` file; i printed `navigator.userAgent` on the screen and this came out correctly... but the logic which is triggered because of this userAgent did not fire !!!